# Group by multiple columns with some having a single value (in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I wish to sum and groupby the type along with the date:

```
 date        size       type

1/1/2020     1          a
1/1/2020     1          a
1/1/2020     1          a
1/1/2020     2          b
1/1/2020     5          b
1/1/2020     6          b
1/1/2020     1          c
2/1/2020     20         a
2/1/2020     21         a
2/1/2020     10         a
2/1/2019     1          b
2/1/2019     4          b     
2/1/2019     5          b
```

Desired output

```
(grouping by type and date to find sum)

  date      size                type
 1/1/2020   3                   a
 1/1/2020   13                  b
 1/1/2020   1                   c
 2/1/2020   51                  a
 2/1/2019   10                  b
```

This is what I am doing:

```
 a.groupby(['type','date']).sum()
```

However, the output is not the desired one, as the type is not showing throughout the dataframe. This is what I am getting:

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

The problem I am having is with :

```
date       size                type
1/1/2020   1                   c
```

since there is only the one value present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
 a.groupby(['type','date']).sum()
```

you get a new data frame with MultiIndex: `type` and `Date`. That's how Pandas decides to **display** the dataframe: repeated lower level index is omitted. The second line still have `type == 'a'`.

To match your expected output, i.e. make `type` and `Date` as usual columns with all values, you can chain the above with `.reset_index()` or use:

```
a.groupby(['type','date'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: Oh wow, I was so close! Thank you! Is there a way to show the percent differences and diff values with my output? @Quang Hoang?

Comment: look at `diff` and `pct_change`. But those would only work with numerical/datetime types, so probably use those on your original approach and reset_index later.